# Send money to users in a Facebook application

Tags: facebook

I want to build a Facebook application that takes money from users through Facebook payments system. This application have to send money to a user. Can I do that through the Facebook payments system?

Egidio

Comment: Have you tried the Facebook Docs first? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: I did but I could not find the solution. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: This should get you started. I recommend you accept payments then re route them to the receiver.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/